# Multiple Projects under single Domain Nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, php-fastcgi

I have two projects with the different path locations that need to be configured under a single domain with separate upstream PHP 7.1 and HHVM. I am trying to achieve the goal with nginx alias directive, but it renders 403 Forbidden on my specified location. The default root provided inside the server just works fine.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name site.local;
    root /srv/project1;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    #This renders a 403 forbidden
    location ~ /catalog/category/view/id {
        alias /srv/project2/public;
        index index.laravel.php;
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ index.laravel.php last; }
        location ~ \.laravel\.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
            fastcgi_index index.laravel.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$request_filename;

        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass hhvm-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**HHVM Upstream**
When I try site.local the hhvm upstream just works fine and the page is successfully rendered.

**PHP Upstream**
When I try http://site.local/catalog/category/view/id/11  I get a 403 forbidden error and I see this in nginx error log

```
> site_openresty | 2018/05/21 11:34:43 [error] 6#6: *1 directory index
> of "/srv/project2/public" is forbidden, client: 172.19.0.1, server:
> site.local, request: "GET /catalog/category/view/id/11/??? HTTP/1.1",
> host: "site.local"
```

I have been trying this for 3 days now and tried different solutions provided on Stackoverflow, github and serverfault but none seems to be fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this error to occur is that the file `index.laravel.php` does not exist in the directory `/srv/project2/public`.

Second thing to double-check is ownership and permission of `/srv/project2/public` and its contents.

Make sure that the owner of this directory and the files in it is the user running nginx ( perhaps www-data or nginx ).
Directory mode should be 755 and file mode be 644.

**EDIT:**

I missed the line `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$request_filename;` at the location matched by `/catalog/category/view/id`

You should replace `$request_filename` by `$fastcgi_script_name` so you will end up with `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`

Inside the location, you can use `echo $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` and `echo $document_root$request_filename;`to see the difference between the two.

Do not forget to reload the service ;)

Comment: I am using docker for windows which sets permission to 777 for everything mounted inside it, I don't think permission is a problem here. And yes of course the index.laravel.php exists.

Comment: @Aftab Did you try to access http://site.local/catalog/category/view/id ? Does it give the same result ?

Comment: Yes it doesn't make any difference.